# Why clickonce takes this version as latest?

Tags: clickonce

I have 2 version, one is Stratifications_2017_7_22_24 and the new one is Stratifications_2017_8_1_22. Why clickonce takes as latest Stratifications_2017_7_22_24?

Answer (score 0):

The ClickOnce will look to the "Publish Version" of your application to decide which one is the new one. The Publish Version of a VB.NET application can be check by Right-click the project in solution explorer, select Properties. It's in the Properties of the project.

[image]

Please let me know if my answer is not clear enough, Good luck

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer.
It's clear enough, but did not respond to my question.
After publishing, clickonce detects this version 2017.7.22.24 as newer than 2017.8.1.22. I don't know why.

Comment: Got you, not sure really.